# ansible AND operation with WHEN is failing when using ansible_facts

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Team: I am trying to fail a task when two conditions are not met on a node. `ansible_facts['distribution_version']` and `ansible_facts['distribution']`.

I am passing in two nodes. one node is `20.x` ubuntu and other is `18.x`.

vars/main.yml

```
os_distribution: "Ubuntu"
os_version: "20.04"
```

task is below

```
- name: "Check Base OS Version maps to expected distribution version {{ os_version }}"
  fail:
    msg: "Task failed as unexpected OS version found: {{ ansible_facts['distribution'] }} {{ ansible_facts['distribution_version'] }} on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when:
    - ansible_facts['distribution_version'] is version(os_version, '<')
    - os_distribution != ansible_facts['distribution']
```

result

```
TASK [node-validation : Check Base OS Version maps to expected distribution version 20.04] ***
Tuesday 23 November 2021  20:11:32 +0000 (0:00:17.570)       0:00:17.690 ****** 
skipping: [node1]
skipping: [node2]
```

expected output: observe 18.x below not sure what am i missing to get that.

```
fatal: [node2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Task failed as unexpected OS version found: Ubuntu 18.04 on node2"}
```

When I remove `- os_distribution != ansible_facts['distribution']` then I get expected result as below but I want to satisfy two conditions not just one.

```
[fatal: [node2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Task failed as unexpected OS version found: Ubuntu 18.04 on node2 }}"}
```

reference to ansible_facts

FACTS for 20.x

```
10:17:59  [0;32m        "distribution": "Ubuntu",[0m
10:17:59  [0;32m        "distribution_file_parsed": true,[0m
10:17:59  [0;32m        "distribution_file_path": "/etc/os-release",[0m
10:17:59  [0;32m        "distribution_file_variety": "Debian",[0m
10:17:59  [0;32m        "distribution_major_version": "18",[0m
10:17:59  [0;32m        "distribution_release": "bionic",[0m
10:17:59  [0;32m        "distribution_version": "18.04",[0m
```

FACTS for 20.x

```
10:23:43  [0;32m        "distribution": "Ubuntu",[0m
10:23:43  [0;32m        "distribution_file_parsed": true,[0m
10:23:43  [0;32m        "distribution_file_path": "/etc/os-release",[0m
10:23:43  [0;32m        "distribution_file_variety": "Debian",[0m
10:23:43  [0;32m        "distribution_major_version": "20",[0m
10:23:43  [0;32m        "distribution_release": "focal",[0m
10:23:43  [0;32m        "distribution_version": "20.04",[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a when a list it performs an **AND** of the two expressions. And here is the standard AND truth table.

| Condition 1 | Condition 2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| False | False | False |
| False | True | False |
| True | False | False |
| True | True | True |

Consider your have

```
os_distribution: "Ubuntu"             # variable
ansible_facts.distribution: "Ubuntu"  # fact
```

The Expression `"Ubuntu" != "Ubuntu"` is **`False`**, and since per the truth table if either of the conditions are false, the final result is false. Ansible will only execute the task when the result is true.

Anyway, I suspect to get the result you want should change your `when` to an **OR**, instead of having a list that is joined by an AND.

```
when:
  ansible_facts['distribution_version'] is version(os_version, '<') or
  os_distribution != ansible_facts['distribution']
```

Demonstration playbook + output

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    os_distribution: "Ubuntu"
    os_version: "20.04"
    ansible_facts:
      distribution: "Ubuntu"
      distribution_file_parsed: True
      distribution_file_path: "/etc/os-release"
      distribution_file_variety: "Debian"
      distribution_major_version: "18"
      distribution_release: "bionic"
      distribution_version: "18.04"

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {{ os_distribution }} {{ansible_facts['distribution'] }}
        {{ os_distribution != ansible_facts['distribution'] }}
  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {{ ansible_facts['distribution_version'] }} {{ os_version }}
        {{ ansible_facts['distribution_version'] is version(os_version, '<') }}

  - name: "Check Base OS Version maps to expected distribution version {{ os_version }}"
    debug:
      msg: "Task failed as unexpected OS version found: {{ ansible_facts['distribution'] }} {{ ansible_facts['distribution_version'] }} on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
    when:
      ansible_facts['distribution_version'] is version(os_version, '<') or
      os_distribution != ansible_facts['distribution']

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    os_distribution: "Ubuntu"
    os_version: "20.04"
    ansible_facts:
      distribution: "Ubuntu"
      distribution_file_parsed: true
      distribution_file_path: "/etc/os-release"
      distribution_file_variety: "Debian"
      distribution_major_version: "20"
      distribution_release: "focal"
      distribution_version: "20.04"

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {{ os_distribution }} {{ansible_facts['distribution'] }}
        {{ os_distribution != ansible_facts['distribution'] }}
  - debug:
      msg: >-
        {{ ansible_facts['distribution_version'] }} {{ os_version }}
        {{ ansible_facts['distribution_version'] is version(os_version, '<') }}

  - name: "Check Base OS Version maps to expected distribution version {{ os_version }}"
    debug:
      msg: "Task failed as unexpected OS version found: {{ ansible_facts['distribution'] }} {{ ansible_facts['distribution_version'] }} on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
    when:
      ansible_facts['distribution_version'] is version(os_version, '<') or
      os_distribution != ansible_facts['distribution']

# Output

# TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "msg": "Ubuntu Ubuntu False"
# }
#
# TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "msg": "18.04 20.04 True"
# }
#
# TASK [Check Base OS Version maps to expected distribution version 20.04] ***************************************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "msg": "Task failed as unexpected OS version found: Ubuntu 18.04 on localhost"
# }
#
# PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************
#
# TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "msg": "Ubuntu Ubuntu False"
# }
#
# TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "msg": "20.04 20.04 False"
# }
#
# TASK [Check Base OS Version maps to expected distribution version 20.04] ***************************************************************
# skipping: [localhost]
#
```

PS, if you want the math on why you switch from an AND to an OR on negation see [De_Morgan's_laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: agree and I believe that is what i thought am doing? I have one node1 that is TT and other is TF. so I should have got failure for node2 that prints message and skip on node1 that has TT with no message. but am getting skip and no message in both situations

Comment: If you need more added an example playbook and output that may help, and you can use to test more.